# Random math game in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, dom

I'm trying to make a math game in JS like this:

> Easy level: This level contains 5 questions contains three digits for example 1 + 2;
> 2 marks are calculated for each question. If the student gets a 7, he is congratulated by a moving animation and music of success, and if he does not get a passing mark, the sound of loss is heard.

and I want to show what's the score he got from correct answers.

> like this sample output:
> you lose and got 0/5, something like that.

I already do that and I did not get the output as I want, I think I have errors in the if statement.

**This is my HTML code**

```
    <section>
        <h1>Math Addition Quiz Game</h1>
        <div class="centerdiv">
            <div class="insertBox">
                <div class="box1">
                    <p id="v1"> </p>
                    <p class="text-center justify-content-center" id="final"></p>
                    <p class="text-center justify-content-center" id="final1"></p>

                </div>
                <div class="box1">
                    <p id="operator">+</p>
                </div>
                <div class="box1">
                    <p type="text" id="v2"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="middleBox">
                <input type="text" id="answ">
            </div>
            <div class="sentBox">
                <button onclick="jsGame()" class="mb-3" id="submit"> Check Answer</button> <br>
                <button onclick="Restart()" class="mb-3"id="restart" > Restart </button> 
                <button onclick="Main()" id="Main"> Back To Main Menu</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

**This is Java Script Code**

```
        let n1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10+1)
        let n2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1)
        document.getElementById('v1').innerHTML = n1;
        document.getElementById('v2').innerHTML = n2;
        var count = 0;
        var wrong = 0;
        var score = 0;
        document.getElementById('v1').value = n1;
        document.getElementById('v2').value = n2;
        document.getElementById('restart').style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById('Main').style.visibility = "hidden";
        let ans = n1 + n2;
        const jsGame = () => {
            var usera = document.getElementById('answ').value;
            if (usera == ans) {
                audio.play();
                wrong = 0; //wrong answers
                score++;
                count++; //correct answers
                GenerateRandom();
            }
            else {    
                //sad.play();
                wrong = wrong+1;
                document.getElementById('answ').value = " ";
                alert(`Correct Answer is ${ans} Try Again. `);
            }

            if (score == 5) {
                level.play();
                Visible();
                var s = 10 - wrong;
                if (s >= 5) {
                level.play();
                    document.getElementById("final").innerHTML = `you win and got ${s}/10`
                    document.getElementsById('submit').style.visibility = "hidden";
                    document.getElementById('operator').style.visibility = "hidden";
                }else{
                    sad.play();
                    document.getElementById('answ').value = " ";
                    document.getElementById("final").innerHTML = `you lose and got ${wrong}/10`

                }
            }  
        
        };

        function GenerateRandom() {
            document.getElementById('answ').value = " ";
            n1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1)
            n2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1)
            document.getElementById('v1').innerHTML = n1;
            document.getElementById('v2').innerHTML = n2;
            document.getElementById('v1').value = n1;
            document.getElementById('v2').value = n2;
            ans = n1 + n2;
        }

        function Restart() {
            window. location. reload();
        }
        function Main() {
            location.href="./game.html";
        }

        var audio = new Audio('../Congratulations-sound.mp3');
        var sad = new Audio('../sad.wav');
        var level = new Audio('../level.wav')


    function Visible() {
                document.getElementById('v1').style.visibility = "hidden";
                document.getElementById('v2').style.visibility = "hidden";
                document.getElementById('answ').style.visibility = "hidden";
                document.getElementById('submit').style.visibility = "hidden";
                document.getElementById('operator').style.visibility = "hidden";
                document.getElementById('restart').style.visibility = "visible";
                document.getElementById('Main').style.visibility = "visible";

    }
```

I hope you can help me, and any modification or better addition to the code please help me. Thank you.

This is a Demo of what I did.

[demo in github](https://deekcs.github.io/MathGame/one.html)

[repo in Github of all codes](https://github.com/DeekCS/MathGame)

Comment: *I think I have errors in the if statement.* what error are you getting?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).